# How can I rewrite all local paths in Git?

Tags: git, github

There is a Git repository that contains a "public_html" folder with a lot of files (paths are `/public_html/example.js`, not `/example.js`). It's not possible to move files in the repository because other people are using a continuous deployment solution that requires this structure.

I want to clone this repository in a way that will remove the leading "/public_html" from all paths, so that `/public_html/example.js` from the repository becomes `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\example.js` on my computer, not `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\public_html\example.js` or `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\repository_name\public_html\example.js`.

How can I do this in Git, without cloning to another location and manually copying the contents of public_html which makes updating files using a simple `git pull` command impossible?